# How to calculate the probability density function for joint distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$, $Y$ be two independent random variable, i.e. $X$~$Unif$($a, b$), $Y$~$Unif$($c, d$).
Set $W$ = $X$+$Y$, $V$ = $X$ - $Y$, what is the joint density function for $P(W,V)$?

How about $V$ = $XY$?

It is a question that I didn't know since freshmen, but I would like to figure it out now.

Comment: There's a general theorem about the sum of independent normals and how it is still normal.

Comment: One way to see this is through characteristic functions. There is a theorem which says that $X =_d Y$ iff $X$ and $Y$ has the same characteristic function. So if you write down the characteristic function of the sum of two independent normal random variable, you will see it is indeed a char. function of a normal distribution.

Comment: @GregoryGrant, oh, I mis-typed the distribution of X,Y, they are both uniform distribution

Comment: @user131605 Why don't you edit your post then.

Comment: I think $W$ and $V$ are not independent if X and Y are uniform distribution

Comment: @GregoryGrant, thanks, I just edited it

Answer (score 1):

So you set $W=X+Y$ and $V=X-Y$.  Solving for $X$ and $Y$ yields

$$X=\frac{W+V}{2}\text{ and }Y=W-\frac{W+V}{2}$$

Now we can use the transformation of variable formula to get the joint distribution of $(W,V)$, i.e.,

$$f_{W,V}(w,v)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)\times|J|$$ where $|J|$ is the Jacobian.

I'm too lazy to do the work, but that should get you started.